# Resizing of HTML textarea

Tags: html, http, servlets

Is it possible to send the resizing done of a html text area on browser back to the server?

I have a simple servlet which sends out a form containing a textarea ? User on browser can fillup the form, resize the text-area and click on submit. I get the data in the post call , but not able to figure out on how can i find out the resizing info of textarea ?

Comment: Do you mean getting the final dimensions of the textarea when the data is submitted or the actual resize operation(s)? What do you intend to do with the information?

Comment: I want to preserve the dimensions. When use clicks on submit , i respond back with the form again with some additional parameter in the html body. I dont want to respond back with the default form size , rather i want to preserve the size so that use dont have to resize it everytime.( thats one of my requirement use case )

Comment: Then you should probably send just an Ajax call instead of form submission. No reason to leave the page when you specifically want to preserve its appearance as modified by the user.

Comment: I am new on this (ajax atc.) , could you please provide me sample code.

Comment: that would not be an answer to the question asked here. You should ask a new question about your original problem, or about using Ajax in a specific situation after checking some primer and making some attempts at addressing your problem with Ajax.

Comment: Well anything which resolves my problem would be answer to my question( javascript and jquery are the solutions to my problem , using which I actually could achieve what i wanted ). Nevertheless , thanks for your suggestion , i would try exploring the AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('id-of-textarea').style.width
document.getElementById('id-of-textarea').style.height
```

Your Javascript can put these in hidden fields in the form before submitting it.

Comment: Thanks , I could achieve it with your solution. Ajax seems to be the perfect solution for my use case as pointed out by Jukka , i will try exploring that.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to extract the height and width of the text area.

Next, subtract the calculated values from the actual height and width values.

Next, you can create a new input element and insert those values into it onSubmit.

This would be inside your "onSubmit" function

```
var ht = $( "#{textarea id}" ).height();
var wd = $( "#{textarea id}" ).width();

var $form = $( "#{form id}" )
        .append('<input type="hidden" name="height" value="'+ht+'" />')
        .append('<input type="hidden" name="width" value="'+wd+'" />');

... continue with the submit ...
```

Or just use pure JS to extract and create the elements inside your onSubmit function.